# How to detach ssh session without killing a running process?

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I started a test filesystem resize on a server through ssh, but totally forgot to do that on a `screen` session. Now it is running, and my laptop has very slow internet. Is there any way that I can keep it running if I loose the ssh connection?

It also outputs progress, but I don't have to care about getting that.

OS: RHEL7.2 equivalent (SL7).

It's probably better to link this as the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup

don't know how to link that instead of the suggested one though, so feel free to add that and mark as duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use `reptyr`

This is exactly the case [`man 1 reptyr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reptyr) explicitly mentions:

> `reptyr` is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching it to a new terminal. Started a long-running process over ssh, but have to leave and don't want to interrupt it? Just start a `screen`, use `reptyr` to grab it, and then kill the ssh session and head on home.

(The manual mentions `screen`, you can use `tmux` instead, whichever you prefer).

Don't miss this note:

> `reptyr` depends on the `ptrace(2)` system call to attach to the remote program. On Ubuntu Maverick and higher, this ability is disabled by default for security reasons. You can enable it temporarily by doing
>
> ```
> echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
> ```
>
> as root, or permanently by editing the file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`, which also contains more information about this setting.

If the file doesn't exist but the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory does, then it's probably enough to create it with the following content:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

The setting will be applied at the next reboot. Please see security considerations below.

---

#### Basic usage

Basic usage is simple:

```
reptyr PID
```

where `PID` is the PID of the process you want to attach to a new terminal. Note `reptyr` only attaches a process to another terminal. This does not mean the process becomes a child of the new shell.

---

#### Security considerations

Setting `ptrace_scope` as `0` is not recommended.

> As Linux grows in popularity, it will become a larger target for malware. One particularly troubling weakness of the Linux process interfaces is that a single user is able to examine the memory and running state of any of their processes. For example, if one application (e.g. Pidgin) was compromised, it would be possible for an attacker to attach to other running processes (e.g. Firefox, SSH sessions, GPG agent, etc) to extract additional credentials and continue to expand the scope of their attack without resorting to user-assisted phishing.
>
> This is not a theoretical problem. SSH session hijacking (http://www.storm.net.nz/projects/7) and arbitrary code injection (http://c-skills.blogspot.com/2007/05/injectso.html) attacks already exist and remain possible if `ptrace` is allowed to operate as before. Since `ptrace` is not commonly used by non-developers and non-admins, system builders should be allowed the option to disable this debugging system.
>
> […]
>
> The sysctl settings (writable only with `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`) are:
>
> `0` - classic `ptrace` permissions: a process can `PTRACE_ATTACH` to any other process running under the same uid, as long as it is dumpable […]
>
> `1` - restricted `ptrace`: a process must have a predefined relationship with the inferior it wants to call `PTRACE_ATTACH` on. By default, this relationship is that of only its descendants when the above classic criteria is also met. […]
>
> `2` - admin-only attach: only processes with `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` may use `ptrace` with `PTRACE_ATTACH`, or through children calling `PTRACE_TRACEME`.
>
> `3` - no attach: no processes may use `ptrace` with `PTRACE_ATTACH` nor via `PTRACE_TRACEME`. Once set, this sysctl value cannot be changed.

<sup>([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt))</sup>

A reasonable approach is to set `ptrace_scope` to `2` and then allow `reptyr` to use `ptrace`:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
sudo setcap CAP_SYS_PTRACE+pe /usr/bin/reptyr
```

Don't forget about the file that holds the permanent setting.

Capabilities are stored [in the file's inode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388562/108618). Therefore I won't be surprised if `reptyr` loses the capability when it gets updated (atomically replaced by a new executable).

Comment: I have one question about this nice answer, just to make it clear. I assume I have to login with ssh with another terminal and grab the process from there, right?

Comment: @Ben Not necessarily. If you manage to start `screen` or `tmux` in the same terminal without terminating the process in question (Ctrl+Z?) then another terminal will not be needed. I admit that using a separate terminal would be my first choice though.

Answer (score 25):

Use

```
Ctrl-Z
```

to pause the application and return to the command line.  Then use

```
bg
```

to allow the process to continue in the background.  Finally use

```
disown
```

So that the process won't be closed when you disconnect your session and close your terminal.

The process will continue to run but there's no way to 'reattach' to the terminal to view the output that I'm aware of if you reconnect to a new session.

Comment: I've done `Ctrl z` then `bg`. Now the process seems to be disconnected from the terminal. How do I reconnect it to terminal?

Comment: If you haven’t disowned it yet, I think you can use fg to bring that task back to the foreground?  I’ve started a new job and haven’t been using Linux for a while so my memory might not be correct on this one.

Answer (score 4):

You can totally disassociate a command (in `bash` or `zsh`, possibly other shells) with the `disown` command. The command however may not be happy about this if it requires a tty, in which case see the `reptyr` answer.

```
$ ssh somecentos7system
-bash-4.2$ sleep 252727
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 252727
-bash-4.2$ bg
[1]+ sleep 252727 &
-bash-4.2$ disown
-bash-4.2$ logout
Connection to somecentos7system closed.
$ ssh somecentos7system
-bash-4.2$ pgrep -lf 252727
20089 sleep
-bash-4.2$
```

Another option is to have a screen (or tmux) session automatically started so you can't forget to start one because one was already started for you because you set things up that way. There's other posts elsewhere on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

- ssh into your remote box. type screen Then start the process you
  want.
- Press Ctrl-A then Ctrl-D. This will detach your screen session
  but leave your processes running. You can now log out of the remote
  box.
- If you want to come back later, log on again and type screen -r
  This will resume your screen session, and you can see the output of
  your process.

[src](https://medium.com/@arnab.k/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session-c836010b26a3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `screen` :

```
screen -S ssh -dm bash -c 'sshpass -p <your_ssh_pass> ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222'
```

Answer (score 0):

nohup + disown + closing file descriptors:

```
❯ nl $PWD/hmm.sh; pgrep -fl sleep | wc -l; ssh localhost $PWD/hmm.sh; pgrep-fl sleep | wc -l
  1  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2  nohup sleep 99 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
  3  disown %%
0
1
```