# How to remotely terminate bash shell processes but ensure history is saved?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, history, kill

Occasionally my X11 window manager (i3) locks up, and I'm forced to switch to a Linux virtual console, or SSH into my machine, to regain control.

Usually this happens when I have numerous rxvt windows open, each of which running a bash shell containing tens if not hundreds of lines of useful command-line history collected over many days or weeks.

I'm using `shopt -s histappend` so each bash shell will append its history to the history file when it terminates in an orderly manner. Normally this works very well and it will retain all of my history provided I close each shell cleanly with `exit` or CTRL-D.

But when my window manager locks up, I can't cleanly exit my bash sessions because there's no way to interact with them. ***So I've been trying to find a way to _remotely_ terminate a bash shell in a way that will cause it to write its history to the history file.***

I've tried sending numerous signals, including `SIGHUP`, to both the bash shell process and the containing rxvt process, but none result in a history save.

I've tried to restart i3 but for various reasons this doesn't work (broken RPC socket it appears). Killing the window manager closes all the windows and bash shells and I lose the history from all of them.

I've tried to find a way to inject "CTRL-D" into each shell's `stdin`, but as far as I can tell that's not possible.

I know of ways to make bash save history to the history file after every command, but I prefer not to use these as they mess up the history indices (i.e. `!nnn` doesn't work because `nnn` changes after every command).

Is there a way to do this and rescue my precious history from certain oblivion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reptyr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reptyr).

> `reptyr` is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching it to a new terminal.

See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690) for details. After you attach the desired shell process to your current terminal, you can tell it to `exit` gracefully.

It may not be easy to identify the particular shell process you'd like to attach at the moment though. You will probably use `reptyr` on *any* shell process found by `ps` (or similar tool), then you will check previous commands and only then you will know whether it's the desired session or not.

A way more convenient solution is to use [`tmux`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) or [`screen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) in the first place.

I work with `tmux` on a daily basis and it's a trivial task to reattach from tty2. With the tool I don't need "numerous rxvt windows open". Usually I organize my work like this:

1. Single `konsole` window.
2. One tab per machine (local host directly, plus I `ssh` to few remote ones), `tmux` on each.
3. Inside each `tmux` one window or more (as needed).
4. Inside each window one pane or more (as needed).

These "layers" are marked with corresponding red numbers in the screenshot below. X11 or KDE problems don't affect my shell sessions, as long as I can get to *any* console of the given machine. Only a meltdown of the `tmux` server itself can hurt but I can't remember the last time such a thing happened to me (probably never).

In case "I'm forced to switch to a Linux virtual console, or SSH into my machine, to regain control", all I need is `tmux a` and I have my shell session(s) back, fully functional, as if nothing happened. If I can force my window manager to reload then I don't even need to terminate these shell processes, because I can get back to them from a new `konsole`, `rxvt` or any terminal emulator.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. `reptyr` is exactly what I need. I used to use `screen` all the time but I found the copy/paste and scrollback behaviour to be a show-stopper - does `tmux` do a better job on this front?

Comment: Incidentally, although I could have used `tmux` to rescue my bash sessions if I was already using it, when I shut down i3 my entire machine crashed (probably a video driver issue), so that wouldn't have been ideal either if I didn't instruct each shell to save history first :)

Comment: @meowsqueak Frankly I don't know if `tmux` does a better job. I have no experience with `screen`, so no comparison; and I hardly ever need to copy from `tmux`.

Answer (score 4):

`reptyr` is an amazing solution if available, which is unfortunately not always the case.

When you send a `HUP` to the lost bash after reconnecting, it *does* write out its history. What typically happens though, is that you are doing the `HUP` sending from another bash session, which will overwrite the killed shell's history upon exit.

You want to flush your current shell's history, `HUP` the lost shell, give it a second to flush its own history and then reload the history from disk:

```
$ history -a; kill -HUP 40705; sleep 1; history -r
```

You will end up with full history, both local and dead shell's, in that order.

Tested on `GNU bash 4.1.2(1)-release`.

Comment: Great info - thank you!