# Load terminal from another window into current split pane in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, gnu-screen, split-window

In GNU Screen, I can switch to any window number within a given split. For example:

- Enter `screen` to launch it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> to create a new window. Now there are two windows: window 0 and window 1. The current window is now window 1.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to create a new split.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to the new split.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to load window 0 in this new split.

How can we do a similar thing in Tmux? This is what I have so far:

- Enter `tmux` to launch it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> to create a new window. There are two windows now: window 0 and window 1. The current window is window 1.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> to create a new split pane. The current pane is now the new split pane.
- How can I now load the shell in window 0 into this new split pane?

Is there a way to simulate this behavior of screen in tmux?

Answer (score 3):

Tmux does not support displaying the same pane in two different windows nor does it support displaying the same pane twice in the same window. You can link a whole window to a session without unlinking it from its original session. Or you can place a pane in another window but this will remove the pane from its original window.

In your example you have already created a pane that holds the place for the desired pane. In this case you can swap the two panes with `swap-pane` tmux command. From `man 1 tmux`:

> `swap-pane [-dDU] [-s src-pane] [-t dst-pane]`
>   (alias: `swapp`)
>
> Swap two panes. […] `-d` instructs tmux not to change the active pane.
>
> If `-s` is omitted and a marked pane is present (see `select-pane -m`), the marked pane is used rather than the current pane.

It's even better: if `-s` and `-t` are both ommited and a marked pane is present, the marked pane and the current pane are swapped. At any given time there can be at most one marked pane within the entire tmux server.

> How can I now load the shell in window 0 into this new split pane?

Navigate to the window 0 and mark the pane you want to move (in your example it's the only pane there). You do it with RMB (if mouse is supported) or <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> (where default <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>). Navigate back to the new pane and invoke:

```
tmux swapp
```

The shell where you invoke `tmux swapp` is not automatically destroyed, it's now in the window 0 where the marked pane used to be. In your example it seems you don't need this shell itself, you just need the new pane; if so, consider `tmux swapp && exit` instead. Keep in mind if there is no marked pane (or if the current one is marked) then `tmux swapp` will effectively do nothing. In such case `tmux swapp && exit` will just exit the shell.

Alternatively, *instead* of creating a new split pane you can move the desired pane into the current window in one step.

> `join-pane [-bdhv] [-l size | -p percentage] [-s src-pane] [-t dst-pane]`
>   (alias: `joinp`)
>
> Like `split-window`, but instead of splitting `dst-pane` and creating a new pane, split it and move `src-pane` into the space. […]
>
> If `-s` is omitted and a marked pane is present (see select-pane `-m`), the marked pane is used rather than the current pane.

So instead of <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>:

1. Mark the pane you want to move.
2. Split the pane you want to split:

   - either with `tmux joinp -v` invoked in the shell there;
   - or with <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `joinp -v` <kbd>Enter</kbd>; in particular this is useful when there is no idle shell in the pane you want to split (but don't forget to make the pane current first).

The method with <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> can be used to invoke `swapp` or any other tmux command.

Below there are few notes about manipulating panes from the outside of tmux. The examples use `tmux swapp` but you can invoke `tmux joinp` similarly.

---

`swap-pane` allows you to swap *any* two panes within a tmux server. You can run `tmux swapp` even from the *outside* of tmux, without manually marking and changing panes, if you know how to address the two panes you want to swap. It may be:

```
tmux swapp -s 0:1.1 -t 0:0.0
```

The format is `session:window.pane`, see the manual where it explains `target-pane`. Note these bare numbers are "relative" (at least the `:window.pane` part, I'm not sure about the `session` number). The very first pane `0:0.0` after swapping with `0:1.1` becomes `0:1.1`. On the other hand tmux sessions, windows and panes have their *unique* identifiers (prefixed with `$`, `@` and `%` respectively). In your case the command may be like:

```
tmux swapp -s %2 -t %0
```

But note if the old pane was indeed `%0` at `0:0.0` and the new one was `%2` at `0:1.1` then they are now `%0` at `0:1.1` and `%2` at `0:0.0` respectively. The unique identifier of each pane is "attached" to the content (process) of the pane and "travels" with it. Non-prefixed identifiers of panes depend on total number of panes and their placement within the window.

You can name sessions (`rename-session`) and windows (`rename-window`). This makes identifying panes with `session:window.pane` easier.

---

You can run more than one tmux server. Servers are identified with their socket paths (`-L` option) or socket names (`-S`). The default name is `default`. If you invoke `tmux` without these options from within tmux then it will find the right server (via the `TMUX` environment variable, I think). If you invoke `tmux` without these options from the outside of tmux then it will be like `tmux -S default`. You may want to swap two panes that belong to a non-default tmux server, e.g.:

```
tmux -S other swapp -s 0:1.1 -t 0:0.0
```

Tmux doesn't support swapping panes between servers. The whole point of having two servers is they are separate. If you ever need to swap panes between two semi-separate entities of tmux, these entities should be sessions within a single tmux server. You can swap panes between different sessions.

If you really need to "hijack" a process running under another tmux server, use [`reptyr`](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690). The tool is totally independent from tmux.